# how to find if a control inherited from a base type?

Tags: asp.net

i want to disable validation controls on some conditions.
how can i find that a control is inherited from "BaseValidator"?

note all validator controls are inherited from BaseValidator [(+)](http://www.startvbdotnet.com/aspsite/controls/validation.aspx)

Comment: What .NET language are you using?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) keyword in C# (`Is` in VB.NET) to find out if a control can be cast to a certain type.

```
if(myControl is BaseValidator)
{
}
```

MSDN describes it as:

> Checks if an object is compatible with a given type.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a given variable inherits from a specific class using the [is operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx):

```
if (yourControl is BaseValidator)
{
   //do some stuff
}
```

I hope this can be of some help.